# My mp4 file isn't uploading with php form

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, mp4

I've written some basic PHP code that accompanies an HTML form that uploads image files. It works fine. I want to upload mp4 files now in addition to images. I reconfigured my settings to allow larger files in `my php.ini file`, but I can't get this to work on localhost. I eventually took out all of the fluff out of my code just to test what was going wrong, and I ended up with just this:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"></input>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

And my php page 'add.php' does this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
if (move_uploaded_file($file,$name)) {
    echo $size;
    echo "success";
    } else {
        echo $size;
        echo "failure";
        }
$path = $name;
echo "<img src='$path'>";
```

This works for images still, but not for mp4 files. Keep in mind, the original code was much more involved and had security features. I just started removing things to see what was causing the problem and ended up with the bare bones of my code and still, it would not `upload mp4 files`.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but maybe I've just been staring at it too long to see what's right in front of me. I know there are a lot of similar questions posted, but most of them seem to have to do with a php.ini file that is not configured, and I'm pretty sure mine has been configured correctly. Any help is appreciated.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

So, I echoed my php.ini variables, and apparently they did not save, or for some reason they did not update when I updated my file. The problem is with the file size limit. The only way I know how to change these variables is manually, however, by opening the php.ini file and changing them. Is there another way to do this that will ensure that the changes stay? If so, any direction on how to do that would be helpful. Thanks,

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

Final update, I found the problem. I apparently had multiple php.ini files, and the ones I navigated to on file explorer were not the active ones. Instead, I navigated to the correct one by going to XAMPP control panel, hitting 'config' next to 'Apache' and choosing php.ini. I made the changes, restarted Apache with the control panel, and then it worked. This is obviously not the problem I thought I had, but since I've seen many variations of this problem on this and other sites while looking for an answer, hopefully someone else will see this and be able to get some help.

Comment: Are you able to get the file name when you are uploading an mp4 file?

Comment: Like in a php file try doing this print_r($_FILES) and pls check are you getting mp4 files?

Comment: Do check for upload config whether files other images are restricted. Also try uploading .mp4 by remaning its extension as .png etc.

Comment: Yes, I can get the file name with r_print, but I get this error with the type:[type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1. Also, I guess I should have checked this earlier, but I just tried and realized I can't even play a video that I manually move to the file.

Comment: Okay. I feel dumb. I echoed the actual upload size limit, and for some reason adjusting the upload limit manually didn't save or work. It is just a matter of the upload file limit. That said, any suggestions on how to change that limit if manually changing it in the php.ini file isn't working for some reason?

Comment: It's fixed. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

## Please check Below Code :

```
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file"></input>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
    
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    
        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4');
        
        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                if ($fileSize < 200000000) {
                    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public_html/';
                    $moved = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination.'styleuploads'.$fileNameNew);
                    header("Location: index.php?uploadyay");
                    exit;
                } else echo "Opps, your file is too big! It needs to be smaller than 200 Megabytes";
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading your file";
            }
        } else {
            echo "You can not upload files of that type";
        }
        
    }   
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: This shows how to upload a file of type mp4, but it does not give an answer to the question I posted. My question was why the code I had wasn't allowing an upload. The question is now solved, and I posted an update explaining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I apparently had multiple php.ini files, and the ones I navigated to on file explorer were not the active ones. Instead, I navigated to the correct one by going to XAMPP control panel, hitting 'config' next to 'Apache' and choosing php.ini. I made the changes, restarted Apache with the control panel, and then it worked. This is obviously not the problem I thought I had, but since I've seen many variations of this problem on this and other sites while looking for an answer, hopefully someone else will see this and be able to get some help.